# Flurry records missing for Sudan, Cuba, Iran and Syria

Tags: flurry, google-play-developer-api, flurry-analytics

Flurry has not been returning results from the Sudan, Cuba, Iran and Syria which it used to return before. Google play however returns similar usage report. Is it because of legal issues(trade embargo) or Flurry themselves chose to ignore these countries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The countries you mention, along with North Korea, are all covered by trade embargo.